# drop down list that populate with what I choose

Tags: java, sql, jsp, foreach

```
   <sql:query sql=" SELECT stockqty FROM STOCKS " dataSource="${Derbydata}" var="STOCKS2" />
<sql:query sql=" SELECT stockid FROM STOCKS" dataSource="${Derbydata}" var="STOCKS1" />
  <strong>Select a product :</strong>
    <select name="stockid">
     <c:forEach var="row" items="${STOCKS1.rowsByIndex}">
      <option><c:out value="${row[0]}"/></option>
     </c:forEach>
    </select>
    </p>

    <p>
        <% String request1 = request.getParameter("stockid"); %>
     <c:forEach var="row" items="${STOCKS2.rowsByIndex}">
      <option><c:out value="${row[0]}"/></option>
     </c:forEach>
    </p>
```

Okay guys. I'm trying to do this. I'm trying to have 2nd dropdownlist and then when I choose from the first drop down list, I will get the 2nd dropdownlist populated with the selected stockid.
I was going to write the sql query like this `SELECT stockqty FROM STOCKS WHERE stockid = :id` but I don't know whether this can be used or not and I don't know where it can get the parameter from. Help please.

Comment: it can be done. if you want to populate the second drop-down list with data from database, you can make an ajax call to the DB and populate the dropdown with the returned data using javascript/jQuery

Comment: Don't think you can do it like this. You would either need to use Ajax or do a form resubmission.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<sql:query var="STOCKS1" dataSource="${Derbydata}">
     SELECT stockqty FROM STOCKS WHERE stockid = ?
    <sql:param value="${id}" />
</sql:query>
```

Comment: where can i set the param ? which part ? I mean in the loop.

Comment: As per `SELECT stockqty FROM STOCKS WHERE stockid = :id` am assuming you have id handy i am expecting it to be at request/session level.